# How can Launchpad be configured to keep layout after reboot?

Tags: macos, launchpad

I updated to Yosemite. I organized my launchpad but when I turned my laptop on after shutting it down, my apps weren't grouped together like I did before.

What do I need to do to keep the layout I defined?